# Create an array before saving/validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, validation

I'm using selectize gem for this task and can't understand how to add values without `{}` to those would be saved correctly. I have `array: true` on this column, so values must be sent in an array, not the string.

I tried convert this attribute before saving of record, but still no result.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :convert_to_array

  def convert_to_array
    self.tags = tags.split(",")
  end
end
```

Error

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{{}}"
```

---

If there aren't callbacks

```
    Parameters: {"post"=>{"title"=>"Aliquam laborum consequatur voluptatem quo.",
"tags"=>"asdas,zxzx"}, "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1", "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"4"}
```

Comment: show the migration of the model ...`Post` ,, for the column `tags`.

Comment: `t.string :tags, array: true`

Comment: from where you are  getting the value of `tags` here `tags.split`

Comment: can you override the setter method for `tags` attribute and set the tag after splitting.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the controller (because `params` is not available in your model):

```
tags = params['post']['tags'].split(',')
@post = Post.new
@post.update_attributes(tags: tags)
```

Comment: Yes.. I have the same doubt.

Comment: Yeah, `params` is not available to the model.

Comment: `@post.update_attribute(:tags, tags)` I guess. Thank you, it works for me.

Comment: Both should work. I used `update_attributes` because it will run the validation. Whereas `update_attribute ` doesn't validate the record.